# what need to be done between continuous integration and continuous delivery

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

According to my understanding, continuous integration means whenever a developer checkin the code to a branch, the code is automatically built, unit test (or other basic test) and then merged to master branch. one tool to do that is Jenkins.

continuous delivery means the code is always READY to be or CAN be deployed, though it may not be deployed.

so what else should be done to move the step from continuous integration to continuous delivery? package the code after more detailed tests like integration/performance/stress tests, tests in difference OS, in different stages (test, production),etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a long and a short answer. The short one is: automate all the steps of packaging and deploying to production and create safety net that automatically checks that the software is ready for release.

The first includes automation database migration taking into consideration zero time deployment (if needed), packaging the binaries, updating configuration files, gradually deploying to different data centers.

The second includes creating test suites for functional and non functional tests. Such as performance, load testing, security penetration, licensing etc.